# How to get risk level field from json

Tags: php, json, shopify

I created one app using php used for download all the details from shopify store.

In shopify docs, there are several orders risk json located. but can't able to take that.

How to add JSON from my code?

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/shopify.php';

$t  = "4226b767fd10efdcbe234ab0c449eda6";
$sc = new ShopifyClient(
    "https-selvar-myshopify-com.myshopify.com", $t, API_KEY, SECRET
);

if (!isset($t))
{
    if (!isset($_GET['signature']))
    {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }

    if (isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token=".$accTok;exit;
        $orders = $sc->call(
            'GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published')
        );

        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}

if(isset($t))
{
    $orders = $sc->call(
        'GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published')
    );

    print_r($orders);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to get the risk level of an order, see [this discussion](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/risk-assessment-value-in-order-api-141571) on the Shopify forums.

However, you can [get all Order Risks for an Order](http://docs.shopify.com/api/order_risks#index) with `/admin/orders/#{id}/risks.json`.

Comment: Already i referenced these link, but sure using one of the json from shopify docs. but i don't know what is exact way?

Comment: on this /admin/orders/#{id}/risks.json don't have risk level right?

Comment: @user3751061 No, it doesn't have the risk level, it has all the risks for an order. If the risk level was available via the API, I would think it would be a property on Order. I'm fairly sure the risk level is not currently in the API.

Comment: Ok, according to your point of view. how to did in shopify? That possible means, we are also possible to do that.